# Remove Element From String Array Using LINQ Contains Value

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I am trying to remove all the elements from a string array that contains a specific value. In this case, my string array contains bunch of files with their folder structure that will be zipped on a later operation. I need to exclude specific files that contains lets say "CDN" values.

Example string structure would be like this

```
C:\Production\Websites\WebSite1\index.html
C:\Production\Websites\WebSite1\product.html
C:\Production\Websites\CDN\content.html
C:\Production\Websites\CDN\frame.html
C:\Production\Websites\WebSite2\index.html
C:\Production\Websites\WebSite2\product.html
```

Values are just example... But I need to remove elements from the list completely from the list that contains "\CDN\".

This is how I get the folders.

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Production\Websites", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

I tried something like this, but apparently I got stuck...

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Production\Websites", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(s => !s.Contains("CDN"))....???
```

Any ideas?
Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The `EnumerateFiles` and `GetFiles` methods differ as follows: When you use `EnumerateFiles`, you can start enumerating the collection of names before the whole collection is returned; when you use `GetFiles`, you must wait for the whole array of names to be returned before you can access the array. Therefore, when you are working with many files and directories, `EnumerateFiles` can be more efficient.

so: enumerate files, filter sequence and make a resulting array

```
string[] files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Production\Websites", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                          .Where(s => !s.Contains("CDN"))
                          .ToArray();
```